# Manage common Model in Typescript End-to-End Applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, typescript

we're currently writing an application with Typescript. Frontend Angular 2, Backend NodeJS+MongoDb.

Since many times, the frontend and backend use the same classes, we wanted to have a common model. Logically, a module with classes and interfaces would be implemented and both front- and backend depend on such module.

Now if said module describes our data-model which is linked to MongoDB, it itself relies on MongoDB (e.g. for ObjectID). Now our frontend relies (indirectly) on MongoDB. Thats kind of odd though isnt it?

There's also another problem:
Our Backend uses require.js, the frontend (due to a2) uses system.js. Now if i have tsc -w running in my "model" project, and then add the dependency on this model in the package.json, the frontend gets the "wrong" js files, because the backend is compiled to require.js not system.js.

So what is better?

Having 2 separate Model declarations one for the frontend one for the backend, specific to its needs --> Duplication of Code

Or somehow bend the toolchain and everything around it so you have one common code base but need to have some way of creating 2 compiled versions of the model, one for the frontend and one for the backend with the respective module systems etc?

Comment: I think this is a question that's better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Still, as an  short answer, I would make the model contain only d.ts files and have the other products either implement or import the interfaces in it.

Comment: @toskv when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat I am not able to flag it to be moved to another website. :(

Comment: @toskv this is [explained here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300348/839601)

Comment: will it solve my problem though if i only have interfaces in the model? I'd still have the mongodb dependency and the whole long roundtrip rebuild npm update stuff..